# Inner Join with Subsonic

Tags: subsonic, inner-join

I am trying to display all records that match the last name entered into a textbox.
This requires an INNER JOIN on the "volID" column because there are 2 tables.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="lName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
<asp:linkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            GridView1.DataSource = new Select("*")
            .From(PastAwardName.Schema)
            .InnerJoin(PastAwardName.VolIDColumn, PastAwardType.VolIDColumn)
            .Where(PastAwardName.Columns.LName).IsEqualTo(this.lName.Text)
            .ExecuteReader();

            GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I tried to do this from and example on Subsonics site but cannot get it working. Geeting the error below.

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 
________________________________________
The objects "dbo.pastAwardNames" and "dbo.pastAwardNames" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The objects "dbo.pastAwardNames" and "dbo.pastAwardNames" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Source Error: 

Line 30: 
Line 31: 
Line 32:         GridView1.DataSource = new Select("*")
Line 33:             .From(PastAwardName.Schema)
Line 34:             .InnerJoin(PastAwardName.VolIDColumn, PastAwardType.VolIDColumn)
```

Comment: Where/how is the second table defined? It appears from the error that it's trying to join the same table to itself.

Comment: PastAwardName is the 1st table - PastAwardType is the 2nd table. I am trying to join on the volID column.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to this, and discovered this page by searching on the error text "in the FROM clause have the same exposed names" and SubSonic 2.2.

Anyway, thought I would post my code, which works perfectly in Subsonic 2.2 and looks quite clean..

Hope somebody finds it useful as it had me scratching my head for a while!!

```
IDataReader reader = new SubSonic.Select(CityMapping.MasterCityColumn, CityMapping.ChildCityColumn, CityMappingTourType.TourTypeCodeColumn)
                .From<CityMapping>()
                .InnerJoin(CityMappingTourType.CityMappingIDColumn, CityMapping.IdColumn)
                .OrderAsc(CityMapping.Columns.MasterCity, CityMapping.Columns.ChildCity, CityMappingTourType.Columns.TourTypeCode)
                .ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your join line needs to be reversed.

```
.InnerJoin(PastAwardName.VolIDColumn, PastAwardType.VolIDColumn)
```

should be

```
.InnerJoin(PastAwardType.VolIDColumn, PastAwardName.VolIDColumn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replies. It is now working using the following code:

```
private void BuildGridView1()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = new Select(PastAwardName.Schema.TableName + ".*", PastAwardType.Schema.TableName + ".*")
              .From(PastAwardName.Schema)
              .InnerJoin(PastAwardType.Schema.TableName, PastAwardType.Columns.VolID, PastAwardName.Schema.TableName, PastAwardName.Columns.VolID)
              .Where(PastAwardName.Columns.LName).Like(this.txtSearchName.Text)
              .OrderAsc(PastAwardType.Columns.AwardYear)
              .ExecuteDataSet();
    }

    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        BuildGridView1();
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query seems right, not sure what the problem is.

Can you rewrite it by creating a simple collection and then bind it to the grid view and see if you are getting the same error?

Did you check out this [link?](http://subsonicproject.com/querying/select-queries/)

Comment: This works fine, but only uses one table. Not sure how to add the join?

GridView1.DataSource = new Query(CMS.PastAwardName.Schema).WHERE(PastAwardName.Columns.LName, this.lName.Text).ExecuteReader();

Comment: There are 2 tables: PastAwardName, PastAwardType 

PastAwardName: volID, fName, lName, district 

PastAwardType: volID, awardName, awardYear, awardType

Comment: as the link provides, why dont you create a collection first and then bind it.

Comment: I looked at the link, but not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think we fixed this in 2.2 - but i do recall a fix in 2.1 as well. Have you tried using the overload for InnerJoin which takes four params?

Sounds like you're using 2.1 - if so you can try 2.2 as I think we have a fix in place for this. Also - InnerJoin has some overloads where you can explicitly tell it which tables and columns to join on.

Comment: Version 2.1. I am new to Subsonic and not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon the same problem.
The problem is that I cannot (or at least don't know how) to define the columns from the second table within a join without building the selectpart like Brett mentioned

```
DB.Select(Table1.Schema.TableName + "." + Table1.Columns.Id,
          Table1.Schema.TableName + "." + Table1.Columns.Name,
          Table2.Schema.TableName + "." + Table2.Columns.Caption
         ).From<Table1>()
          .LeftOuterJoin(Table2.Table1_IdColumn, Table1.IdColumn);
```

works, but it would be nead to use

```
DB.Select(Table1.IdColumn, Table2.CaptionColumn)
  .From<Table2>()
  .LeftOuterJoin(Table2.Table1_IdColumn, Table1.IdColumn);
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to this problem is fairly annoying but it works. Your code has the join statement like this:

```
.From(PastAwardName.Schema)
.InnerJoin(PastAwardName.VolIDColumn, PastAwardType.VolIDColumn)
```

If you change the table order in your InnerJoin statement so that the table in your from statement is second instead of first it will work.

```
.From(PastAwardName.Schema)
.InnerJoin(PastAwardType.VolIDColumn, PastAwardName.VolIDColumn)
```

Very annoying behaviour...